# How to parse JSON nested objects?

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

can anyone please show me how I can parse a JSON nested object so that I can access the values of each? I have only been able to parse the root objects...

```
[
{
    "direction_id": "0",
    "stops": [
        {
            "stop_id": "3734",
            "stop_code": "5266",
            "stop_name": "WB @78 AV TERMINAL",
            "stop_desc": "",
            "stop_lat": 51.122802,
            "stop_lon": -114.070807,
            "zone_id": "",
            "stop_url": "",
            "location_type": "",
            "parent_station": "",
            "agency_key": "calgary-transit",
            "loc": [
                -114.070807,
                51.122802
            ],
            "_id": "54ff06c07ec9b14c0412a602"
        },
        {
            "stop_id": "2750",
            "stop_code": "5268",
            "stop_name": "EB 78 AV@HUNTHAM RD NE",
            "stop_desc": "78 AV NE & HUNTHAM RD NE",
            "stop_lat": 51.121726,
            "stop_lon": -114.066023,
            "zone_id": "",
            "stop_url": "",
            "location_type": "",
            "parent_station": "",
            "agency_key": "calgary-transit",
            "loc": [
                -114.066023,
                51.121726
            ],
            "_id": "54ff06c07ec9b14c0412a280"
        },
        {
            "stop_id": "2751",
            "stop_code": "9010",
            "stop_name": "EB 78 AV@HUNTRDG HL NE",
            "stop_desc": "78 AV NE & HUNTRIDGE HL NE",
            "stop_lat": 51.121179,
            "stop_lon": -114.061799,
            "zone_id": "",
            "stop_url": "",
            "location_type": "",
            "parent_station": "",
            "agency_key": "calgary-transit",
            "loc": [
                -114.061799,
                51.121179
            ],
            "_id": "54ff06c07ec9b14c0412a281"
        },
        {
            "stop_id": "2752",
            "stop_code": "9011",
            "stop_name": "EB 78 AV@HUNTINGTON RD NE",
            "stop_desc": "78 AV NE & HUNTINGTON RD NE",
            "stop_lat": 51.12102,
            "stop_lon": -114.058805,
            "zone_id": "",
            "stop_url": "",
            "location_type": "",
            "parent_station": "",
            "agency_key": "calgary-transit",
            "loc": [
                -114.058805,
                51.12102
            ],
            "_id": "54ff06c07ec9b14c0412a282"
        },
```

So I am trying to parse each stop_id, for example and seem unable to find how I can set the object to "stops" so I can loop through each. Any ideas on the best way to do this?

EDIT: Sorry the rest of my post must have gotten deleted before I submitted, adding the rest of it now:

Once I have the JSON downloaded (json) I try to parse it like so, and the log is just one line with all the data in it as one...

```
            for(int n = 0; n < json.length(); n++)
            {
                try {
                    JSONObject object = json.getJSONObject(n);

                    String short_name = object.getString("stops");



                    Log.v("PARSE",short_name);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

How can I set "stops" as an Object? or is it an ObjectArray?? so that I can loop through each value and get each stop_id?

Comment: There are lot of tutorials how to do this parsing ! Did you try google ? First 5 responses give you all information about it. For example : http://www.androidhive.info/2014/09/android-json-parsing-using-volley/

Comment: yes, I did try google... :(  I can parse the root object values of other json just fine, just don't seem to be able to for loop through the values of a nested object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException {
        JSONObject j = new JSONObject("{\"stops\": [{\"stop_id\": \"3734\",\"stop_code\": \"5266\"},{\"stop_id\": \"2750\",\"stop_code\": \"5268\"}]}");        
        JSONArray array = j.getJSONArray("stops");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            System.out.println(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("stop_id"));
        }
    }
```

This code prints 3734 and 2750, the stop_id of each element of array.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

Thanks all for the assistance.

```
  for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++){

            try {

                JSONObject stops =json.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONArray array = stops.getJSONArray("stops");

                for (int st = 0; st < array.length(); st++) {

JSONObject currentStop = array.getJSONObject(st);
                    String stop_desc = currentStop.getString("stop_name");
                    String stop_id = currentStop.getString("stop_id");
                    String stop_code = currentStop.getString("stop_code");

           }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Instead call array.getJSONObject(st) for each field (name, id, code) call it only once and assign a variable. Thus your code will be more efficient. ;)

Comment: I'm confused how to do this, I thought that's what I was currently doing with String stop_id = array.getJSONObject(st).getString("stop_id");?     Could you possibly explain a bit more :). Thanks!

Comment: I send a suggestion to you. I believe that my comment had been clearer.

Comment: Huh? Well as I explained , it's not 100% clear what you meant, thanks anyways, Cheers

Comment: Strange....I edit your post for show my suggestion. You dont receive my edition? I believe that you need approve.

Comment: I was on mobile and it wasn't showing up, brilliant! I got it now :)

Thanks a ton!